# using the apcluster package in R, it is possible to "score" unclustered data points

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am new to R and I have a request that I am not sure is possible.  We have a number of retail locations that my boss would like to use affinity propagation to group into clusters. We will not be clustering based on geographic location. Once he has found a configuration he likes, he wants to be able to input other locations to determine which of those set clusters they should fall into.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to use the same options and re-cluster with the original points and the new ones added in, however I believe that this might change the outcome.

Am I understanding this right, or are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clustering is not a drop-in replacement for classification.

Few clustering algorithms can meaningfully integrate new information.

The usual approach for your problem however is simple:

1. Do clustering.
2. use the cluster labels as class labels
3. train a classifier
4. apply the classifier to the new data

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the late answer, I just incidentally stumbled over your question.

I agree with Anony-Mousse's answer that clustering is the first step and classification is the second. However, I'm not sure whether this is the best option here. Elena601b is obviously talking about a task with truly spatial data, so my impression is that the best approach is to cluster first and then to "classify" new points/samples/locations by looking for the closest cluster exemplar. Here is some code for synthetic data:

```
## if not available, run the following first:
## install.packages("apcluster")

library(apcluster)

## create four synthetic 2D clusters
cl1 <- cbind(rnorm(30, 0.3, 0.05), rnorm(30, 0.7, 0.04))
cl2 <- cbind(rnorm(30, 0.7, 0.04), rnorm(30, 0.4, .05))
cl3 <- cbind(rnorm(20, 0.50, 0.03), rnorm(20, 0.72, 0.03))
cl4 <- cbind(rnorm(25, 0.50, 0.03), rnorm(25, 0.42, 0.04))
x <- rbind(cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4)

## run apcluster() (you may replace the Euclidean distance by a different
## distance, e.g. driving distance, driving time)
apres <- apcluster(negDistMat(r=2), x, q=0)

## create new samples
xNew <- cbind(rnorm(10, 0.3, 0.05), rnorm(10, 0.7, 0.04))

## auxiliary predict() function
predict.apcluster <- function(s, exemplars, newdata)
{
    simMat <- s(rbind(exemplars, newdata),
                sel=(1:nrow(newdata)) + nrow(exemplars))[1:nrow(exemplars), ]
    unname(apply(simMat, 2, which.max))
}

## assign new data samples to exemplars
predict.apcluster(negDistMat(r=2), x[apres@exemplars, ], xNew)

## ... the result is a vector of indices to which exemplar/cluster each
## data sample is assigned
```

I will probably add such a `predict()` method in a future release of the package (I am the maintainer of the package). I hope that helps.